# htaccess rewrite that will look for a filename the same as the directory name to server as an index

Tags: .htaccess

I like to avoid using index.php file names because it gets confusing in my code editor when I have numerous different index.phps open and I don't know which is which until I focus them.

Instead, I like the "index" file to be the same name of the directory I'm in.

Example:

Rather than this:

```
myapp/admin/index.php
myapp/user/index.php
```

I'd have this:

```
myapp/admin/admin.php
myapp/user/user.php
```

Yet I still want my users to be able to go to just myapp/admin/ or myapp/user/ without having to tack on the filename.

Is there a way I can tell htaccess to look for a file matching the name of the directory and treat it as the index?

Answer (score 1):

Write a [RegEx](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). Somewhat like this:

```
RewriteRule myapp/(\w+)/(?:index\.php)? myapp/$1/$1.php
```